# É possivel trocar sistema de rotas ($route) na mesma URL? Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Estou querendo, a partir de uma constante (configuraçao) trocar de controller ou directive que seja na mesma URL.

Por exemplo, imagina que eu estou na pagina inicial e entao, temos o *path* "/" ok. Porém, dependendo da configuração o cara pode mudar isso. Vou colocar um exemplo:

```
angular.module('meuModulo')
  .config(['$routeProvider’, ‘go.svc.config’,  function($routeProvider, config) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'directives/directive1.html',
      controller: function() {
    var conf = config.home;

    if (conf === ‘musica’) {
        return 'controllers/meuControllerMusica',
    } else {
        return ‘controllers/meuControllerHomePage';
    }
   };
  })
}]);
```

A ideia aqui entao seria: De acordo com uma configuraçao especifica, eu trocaria o Controller....até aqui perfeito.

O problema que o *.config* neste caso aceita SOMENTE o `$routerProvider`, entao nao consigo fazer o que quero.

A soluçao mais proxima que cheguei foi deixar um controller fixo (sem ser uma *function*) e dentro dela fazer algo como:

```
$route.current.controller = 'meuControllerMusica';
$route.reload();
```

O problema que se faço isso, ele fica em loop infinito, porque sempre vai ficar no controller antigo, faz a troca e dá o reload.

Alguem ja passou por algo parecido ou teria alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Por quê você quer alternar 2 controllers em 1 view? Por quê não criar uma view por controller? Adicione mais códigos e explique melhor o propósito.
At.

Comment: Não conheço muito de angular mas, o `controller` do `routeProvider` é string? se for, adicione `()` no final da sua função do controller para que seja atribuído a ele o resultado da função e não o objeto do tipo função

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar ng-switch para trocar um elemento DOM que contenha uma diretiva.

Por exemplo:

```
angular.module('meuModulo')
  .config(['$routeProvider’, ‘go.svc.config’,  function($routeProvider, config) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'directives/directive1.html',
      controller: 'main'
   };
  })
}])
    .controller('main', ['$scope', 'go.svc.config', function($scope) {
        var conf = config.home;

        if (conf === ‘musica’) {
            $scope.showView = 'musica';
        } else {
            $scope.showView = 'home';
        }
}]);
;
```

Na view

```
<div ng-controller="main">
    <div ng-switch on="showView">
      <div  ng-switch-when="home" ng-controller="meuControllerHomePage">Settings Div</div>
      <div  ng-switch-when="musica" ng-controller="meuControllerHomePage">Home Span</div>
      <div  ng-switch-default>default</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o roteador nativo do AngularJS tem algumas desvantagens, aconselho vc a usar o Angular Ui-Router.

Segue o link de uma resposta minha sobre ele, dá uma olhada com calma, espero que ajude:

[Como usar Angular UI Router? e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29459/como-usar-angular-ui-router-e-quais-as-vantagens/29815#29815)